# Can't SELECT DISTINCT via Google Fusion Tables REST API

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

In my Fusion Table, my State Abbr. column contains many duplicate values; and I only want to list the different values. So I tried querying the table with

`SELECT DISTINCT 'State Abbr. FROM <table_id>'`

But I got the error below; so, I guess that it doesn't like `SELECT DISTINCT`

> Invalid query: Parse error near 'State Abbr.'

(I'm using the Fusion Tables API through Google Apps Script's advanced services).

I went through the [Row and Query SQL Reference](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#Select) for the Fusion Tables REST API, and don't see a DISTINCT option for SELECT statements. Is there another way to get distinct values, either through the Fusion Tables API or Google Apps Script, that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you could use `SELECT DISTINCT`, try using `GROUP BY` it will return the same results.

```
SELECT State Abbr from TABLEID group by State Abbr
```